# Only one page of product got with rest admin api

Tags: laravel, shopify

I have so many pages of products on my development store.But when I try to use products.json to get all of my products, it only take 50 listings(one page).Could anybody solve my doubt?

```
<?php
 $url = 'https://myshopifystore/admin/api/2019-07/products.json';
 $result = file_get_contents($url);
 $data = json_decode($result, true);
 dd($data);
```

[my result like this picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE3cD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit property on the request has a default of 50 up to 250. In case you want more use a loop to search though every page until the end.

```
GET /admin/api/2019-07/products.json?limit=250?page=1
```

Use

```
GET /admin/api/2019-07/products/count.json
```

to get the total product you want to search.

More info about paginated page [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/paginated-rest-results)

EDIT 1 : The paginated ?page= is now deprecated. It will be remove in version 2020-07. You should use  cursor-based pagination.

Comment: Ok ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Below function can help to fetch resources with cursor based pagination in new shopify API

```
public function request($method,$url,$param = []){
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $url = 'https://'.$this->username.':'.$this->password.'@'.$this->domain.'/admin/api/2019-10/'.$url;
    $parameters = [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ]
    ];
    if(!empty($param)){ $parameters['json'] = $param;}
    $response = $client->request($method, $url,$parameters);
    $responseHeaders = $response->getHeaders();
    $tokenType = 'next';
    if(array_key_exists('Link',$responseHeaders)){
        $link = $responseHeaders['Link'][0];
        $tokenType  = strpos($link,'rel="next') !== false ? "next" : "previous";
        $tobeReplace = ["<",">",'rel="next"',";",'rel="previous"'];
        $tobeReplaceWith = ["","","",""];
        parse_str(parse_url(str_replace($tobeReplace,$tobeReplaceWith,$link),PHP_URL_QUERY),$op);
        $pageToken = trim($op['page_info']);
    }
    $rateLimit = explode('/', $responseHeaders["X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit"][0]);
    $usedLimitPercentage = (100*$rateLimit[0])/$rateLimit[1];
    if($usedLimitPercentage > 95){sleep(5);}
    $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
    $r['resource'] =  (is_array($responseBody) && count($responseBody) > 0) ? array_shift($responseBody) : $responseBody;
    $r[$tokenType]['page_token'] = isset($pageToken) ? $pageToken : null;
    return $r;
}
```

using above function in controller

```
$ids = [];
$nextPageToken = null;
  do{
    $response = $shop->request('get','products.json?limit=250&page_info='.$nextPageToken.'&rel=next');
     foreach($response['resource'] as $product){
        array_push($ids, $product['id']);
     }
            $nextPageToken = $response['next']['page_token'] ?? null;
    }while($nextPageToken != null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your script but when I pass param it says 400 bad reuest truncated. I would like to pass the status => 'any', do you have an idea ?

Comment: try to pass it as url parameter

Comment: @BhargavKaklotara, could the above be done all together in a single Laravel controller. So if you hit a route "/getAllProducts" it would trigger a controller to loop through all products and return all products? I am struggling to figure out the function is being used in a controller?