# First page of product got retrieved with rest admin API in Shopify

Tags: php, pagination, shopify

I have almost 300 products in my development store.

But when I use `product.json` to retrieve, only 250 products are retrieved.

Please help me in solving this.

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57368670/only-one-page-of-product-got-with-rest-admin-api)

My code is:

```php
$nextPageToken = null;
                    
do {                    
                  
  $response = $this->shopify->call1('GET', '/admin/api/2019-07/products.json? 
   limit=250&page_info='.$nextPageToken.'&rel=next' );
                        
  foreach($response['resource'] as $product):$images = array();          
                                           
    foreach ($product['images'] as $image):
      $images[] = $image['src'];
    endforeach;
    
    $products[] = array(
      'shop' => $this->session->userdata('id'),
      'handle' => $product['handle'],
      'title' => $product['title'],
      'product' => $product['id'],
      'vendor' => $product['vendor'],
      'type' => $product['product_type'],
      'images' => json_encode($images),
      'published_at' => $product['published_at']
    ); 
                        
  endforeach;
            
  $this->load->model('shop_products_model');
            
    if ($this->shop_products_model->update($products)) {
      $this->load->model('customers/customers_model');
      $updated = array(
        'shop' => $this->session->userdata('shop'),
        'products_updated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
      );
       
      $this->customers_model->update($updated);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
                                 
      $nextPageToken= isset($response['next']['page_token']) ? $response['next'] 
        ['page_token'] : null;

} while($nextPageToken != null);
```

Comment: I guess the `$nextPageToken` is always being set as null which is why you are getting the first 250 products. Please check the API documentation - https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product?api[version]=2020-04

Comment: I have fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: If you can post your solution for the next who will read this post, it will be great